# HTML/CSS Dropdown menu <li> width

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, width

I want to make a dropdown menu with HTML/CSS and some javascript. I am stuck with the width of the li element. It has to have the width of the content inside instead of a static width.

The problem is when I hover with my mouse over the li element (To show the dropdown menu) it is changing his width.

I created a jsfiddle file that you can find [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/UtzJh/)

CSS:

```
  #nav{
        background-color: #1da8d8;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
    }

    #nav li a i {
        text-align: right;
    }

    #nav ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin:0;
        list-style: none;
        width:12em;
        z-index:99;
        position:relative;
        overflow:visible;
    }

    #nav li {
        background-color: #1b9cc9;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 39px;
        height: 40px;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
        float:left;
        display:block;
    }
    #nav ul li{
        background-color:#1b9cc9;
        top: 20px;
        width: 12em;
        float: left;
    }

    #nav a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
        padding: 0.1em;
        margin: 0 0.2em 0 0;
        height:1.05em;
        width: auto;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover, #nav ul li a:hover{ background-color:#1da8d8;}


    #nav ul{
        display:none;
    }

    /*all see this */
    #nav ul ul, #nav ul ul ul{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:12em;
    }

    /* non-IE browsers see this */
    #nav ul li>ul, #nav ul ul li>ul{
        margin-top:-1.8em;
    }

    #nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul ul{
        display:none;
    }

    #nav li:hover ul, #nav ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul ul ul li:hover ul{
        display:block;
    }

    li>ul {
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The width is now automaticaly adjusted to the complete width of the child. Setting the position of the child to absolute will ignore this.

Change `postition:relative;` on `#nav ul` to `position:absolute;`

```
#nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    width:12em;
    min-width:100%;
    z-index:99;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UtzJh/1/

Comment: **min-width:100%;**  - you forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the width and max-width here too - in your css try this

```
#nav li {
    background-color: #1b9cc9;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 39px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 12em;
    max-width: 12em;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```